# Why is "bits ev" of mouse input device null?

Tags: mouse, input

I use `lsinput` to display mouse device on a device. The mouse related entry is

```
/dev/input/event2
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x413c
   product : 0x301a
   version : 273
   name    : "PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mo"
   phys    : "usb-ff540000.usb-1.1/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

Why values in `bits ev` entry are all `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bits aren’t really `null`, each `(null)` corresponds to a bit set in the descriptor, but for which `lsinput` doesn’t have a name. `lsinput` doesn’t have a name because its build process extracts names from a kernel-provided header file, which changed a while ago in a way [which broke the `lsinput` build process](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873376).

If you build [the latest release](https://www.kraxel.org/releases/input/), you’ll be able to see the bit names again:

```
$ wget https://www.kraxel.org/releases/input/input-1.3.tar.gz
$ tar xf input-1.3.tar.gz
$ cd input-1.3
$ make
$ ./lsinput -v
```

(assuming you have everything needed for the build, basically a C compiler and `make`).